# Jquery Click Event on Dynamically Generated Element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to in-page edit on table data. When I Double Click on table cell, it appends a textbox in which I can edit text. I want to save data at blur event. When the textbox lost focus nothing happened.

Here is code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $n = 1;

    $('.td').dblclick(function () {
        $val = $(this).text();
        $(this).empty().append("<input type='text' id='txtReady"+$n+"' class='txt'>");
        $('#txtReady'+$n).val($val).focus();
        $n++;
    });

    $(document).on("input.txt", "blur", function () {
        alert('blured');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td">Sample Text One</td>
        <td class="td">Sample Text Two</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I have checked click and other events but nothing happened.
I could not find out the problem. So I need help.

Comment: Multiple typographical errors: undeclared variables `$n` and `$val`, bad selector using class syntax `.td` instead of `td`, and reversing the order of the the first two parameters of the `on` method.

Answer (score 3):

Try like below :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $n = 1;

  $('.td').dblclick(function() {
   //getting value
    var val = $(this).text();
    console.log(val);
    $(this).empty().append("<input type='text' id='txtReady" + $n + "' class='txt'>");
    $('#txtReady' + $n).val(val).focus();
    $n++;
  });
//check if blur
 $(document).on('blur','.txt', function() {
    //console.log($(this).val());
    alert("focus gone");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">Sample Text One </td>
    <td class="td">Sample Text Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```